# Javascript script no longer functions

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I need a bit of help fixing some javascript since i modified my magento setup.

I can see why it doesnt work, it's looking for the parent element of the 'a', which was the 'li' but now is one of the Div's i've added. What i can't figure out is how i fix it.

This is the script

```
Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
  initialize: function(selector) {
    var self=this;
    $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
  },

  initTab: function(el) {
      el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
      if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
        this.showContent(el);
      }
      el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
  },

  showContent: function(a) {
    var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
    ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
      var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
      if (el==li) {
        el.addClassName('active');
        contents.show();
      } else {
        el.removeClassName('active');
        contents.hide();
      }
    });
  }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
```

And here is my modified html:

```
    <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>">
        <div class="sidebar-block-2">
        <div class="block-title">
            <div class="title-corners-top"><div><div>&nbsp;</div></div></div>
            <div class="title-border-left">
            <div class="title-border-right">
            <div class="title-border-top">
        <a href="#"><strong><span><?php echo $_tab['title']?></span></strong></a>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </li>
```

I've added from  down to the hyperlink. I think i need to use something like .closest("li"), but i need some help to get it to work.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: what is `$`? what is `$$`? Hard to help without knowing what libraries you are using.

Comment: Could always make a loop (where `this` is your anchor) `curElement=this.parent; while(curElement.tagName!="li"){ curElement=curElement.parent;}`

Comment: You should tag this as prototype.js

Comment: What about `var li = a.up('li'), ul = $(li.parentNode);`?

Comment: jbaby, I'm having a hard time trying to find the answer for you. I'm really useless when it comes to any of this javascript/jquery/prototype, i cant even tell the difference!

We can see a live example here: http://www.kidsoncars.co.uk/12v-twin-motor-raptor-quad.html

The product description/product tags is where the javascript should be used.

Comment: What is `Class.create`, what library do you use? Btw, without arguments it's likely to be equivalent to a plain `function(){}`.

Comment: Sigh... the page in question has _both_ Prototype and jQuery included. But the code shown is definitely of `Prototype` flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this line (instead of `var li = $(a.parentNode), ...`, as now you need the closest parent that is `<li>` element.

```
var li = a.up('li'), ul = $(li.parentNode);
```

Prototype's [Element#up](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/prototype/up/) method travels up the DOM hierarchy until it finds an element matching the given selector. If the search fails, `undefined` is returned.

Comment: This seems to work, the only thing missing is that the when the page is loaded both div's are visible. I can't quite see whats needs changing to fix this either?

Comment: This line - `if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {` - in `initTab` method also needs to be fixed, in the similar way (i.e., with `el.up('li')`).

Answer (score -1):

You want to use prototype's [`element.up()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/up/)